# Why are two IPs responding to my ping?

Tags: mac-osx, mac-osx-server, ping

I'm having a weird issue.  On one of a mac, I noticed it was having some weird issues communicating with the server.  I pinged the server, 2.0.5.90, from the terminal on the mac, and here are the responses I am seeing.

```
64 bytes from 10.0.5.90: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.457 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.5.125: icmp_seq=0 ttl=255 time=4.753 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 10.0.5.90: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.459 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.5.125: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=4.716 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 10.0.5.90: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.288 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.5.125: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=4.742 ms (DUP!)
```

Why would two devices be responding to these pings?

Comment: Does the machine with the IP-address 10.0.5.125 maybe have 10.0.5.90 configured as a secondary address? Although this still would be kinda wonky.

Comment: Is the server NIC teamed?

Comment: Let me guess -- you're trying to talk to a Microsoft Exchange system, and the client access servers are using Network Load Balancing?

Comment: The server has two ethernet interfaces, each with their own IP addresses.. 2.0.5.89 and 2.0.5.90. It's a Mac OS X server.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure it's two devices, try `arp -a` command to list your arp table and see if both ip address are mapped to same mac address in it.

If you're sure they are different devices with different MAC addresses you can try and delete the arp table with `arp -d -a` or just one or both addresses with `arp -d x.x.x.x` an let them repopulate again.

Notice: I could be wrong with the syntax off arp command on macos, it's been a while since I did anything on it.

Comment: I did try arp -d * earlier and I was still seeing the same

Comment: what is the ip and subnet mask on the client you're pinging from. Also are you on wireless or on cable, can you try connecting that client to some other switch